# How to show this space is complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $\mathbb F_q$ be the finite field of $q$ elements. We let $K_{\infty}$ to be the field of formal power series in $x^{-1}$ over $\mathbb F_q$. If 
$$
\alpha = \sum_{- \infty}^{t} a_i x^i,
$$
then we define the valuation
$$
|\alpha| = q^t.
$$
According to the document I am reading, under this valuation $K_{\infty}$ is a locally compact field.

I am trying to show that $K_{\infty}$ is compact
by proving that it is complete and totally bounded.

Could someone please give me a hint/solution on how
to show $K_{\infty}$ is complete?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please ignore as I just realized the question does not even make sense...